# Place container instead of AppBar

Tags: flutter

I need to remove an app bar if a state changes in my app and I need to place a container at the top that will allow me text with custom description. I am trying to place a conditional statement before appBar but it doesn't allow me to. Are there other alternatives?

```dart
   return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
          context.watch<UseData>().hideBar == false ? appBar:
        AppBar(
          // automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
          title:
          Text("Test", style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black
          )),
          centerTitle: true,
 
          bottomOpacity: 0,
          elevation: 2,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
        ) : Container(child: ...)),
```

`Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found. (Documentation)  Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.`

I also tried using positioned, but the top: 0 keeps staying under AppBar, I need a custom container over the app bar.

```dart
     Positioned(
        top: 0,
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text("hi")
            ],
          )
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just change the title instead? and make it center

Comment: @Diwyansh I need picture, description and title, its too much for AppBar

Comment: Check answer please.

Comment: just change the title and wrap with ```center``` maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`appBar` accepts **PreferredSizeWidget** so you can't pass **Container** widget to it directly rather than just Wrap you **Container** into **PreferredSize** widget pass `height` inside `preferredSize` property as per your requirement. Check below code for reference :

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: isAppBar
          ? AppBar(
              title: Text("Title Here"),
            )
          : PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100.00),
              child: Container(
                child: Text("Second Title"),
              ),
            ),
    );
```

Comment: possible to make the height based on the container content?

Comment: I don't think so still I will look for it and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PreferredSize` in `AppBar`

```dart
return Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
            child: context.watch<UseData>().hideBar == false
                ? AppBar(
                    // automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                    title: Text("Test", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                    centerTitle: true,

                    bottomOpacity: 0,
                    elevation: 2,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
                  )
                : Container(),
            preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight)),
      ),
```